# when does a continuous PDF NOT have a limit at infinity

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

I have to find out if it is correct, that if a continuous random variable has an expected value and it's PDF is continuous, then

$$\lim_{t \to +\infty}f_{\xi}(t)= 0$$

I know how to prove that the limit is equal to 0 if we presume it exists. But I'm struggling to understand what happens if it doesn't or how to prove that the limit exists.. I would appreciate any help.

Edit: Thanks for all the answers and comments. They helped me realize what I don't understand: what could be an example of a continuous PDF which has a mean and which limit is not existent?

Edit 2: I've found an example of a continuous function, which integral is 1, but I'm not sure if it has an expected value. Is it possible to calculate it for such a function?
Here's
[its graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vl8F.jpg)

Comment: 1. Start with $\sum_{n\ge 1}  n \mathbf1_{[n,n + 1/n^3)}$. 2. Make it density.  3. Smoothen it. 4. Profit.

Comment: @zhoraster might be a stupid question... but what is $1_{[n, n+1/n^3)}$? Is this a function equal to 1 on $[n, n+1/n^3)$? Not sure how to turn it into density..

Comment: Yes, you got it right. To make it a density, multiply it by something so it integrates to 1.

Comment: @Surb if it's possible, could you write the counter example that you talked about? still struggling to find a proper one

Comment: @zhoraster I may not understand something, but this function seems not to be continuous.. If I write it out I get $1_{[1, 2)} + 2*1_{[2, 2+1/8)} + 3*1_{[3, 3 + 1/27)} +...$. Aren't there blank spaces on $[2+1/8, 3), [3+1/27, 4)$, for example? Then how can it turn into a density function?

Comment: is 'has an expected value' the same as 'integrable' ?

Comment: @BCLC it means that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x| f_{\xi}(x)dx < \infty$, where $f_{\xi}(x)$ is a PDF

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comments say, there could be a counter example. In this answer i am trying to make progress in the positive direction.
$\int_{0}^{\infty} t f_{\zeta} (t) dt = \text{constant} < \infty \implies \lim_{a \rightarrow N}\int_{a}^{\infty} t f_{\zeta} (t) dt \rightarrow 0$, Let $a = N$ then $s_N = \int_{N}^{\infty} t f_{\zeta} (t) dt $ and $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} s_N = 0$. Now since $f_{\zeta} (t) \geq 0$, $\forall t$ => $s_N$ is monotonically decreasing and converges to $0$, in particular $|s_n| < \epsilon_N$, $\forall n \geq N$. Define $E_{mN} = \{x: x \geq N, |f_{\zeta}(x)| > \frac{1}{m}\}$. Let $\mu$ be lebesgue measure. $$\mu(E_{mN}) \frac{N}{m}   < |\int_{E_{mN}} t f_{\zeta} (t) dt | \leq |\int_{N}^{\infty} t f_{\zeta} (t) dt | < \epsilon_N.$$ Hence $$\mu(E_{NN}) < \epsilon_N.$$ Hence $$0\leq \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_{NN}) \leq  \epsilon_N \rightarrow 0.$$ Hence $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_{NN}) = 0.$$ This seems to be the best i can prove. To prove what you want, we need: $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\cup_{m \geq N} E_{mN}) = 0.$$ Thanks.

EDIT:
One of the comments above gives a counter example. So the above seems to be the be best we can prove as a positive result.

Comment: I don't think the claim is true, so try to give a counter-example instead of a half-proof.

Comment: i will try ! Thanks !